# How can i make checkout process in Opencart 3.x on one page with one button "Confirm"?

Tags: php, opencart, opencart-3

How can I make checkout process in Opencart 3.0.1.2 on one page with one button "Confirm"?

I need to leave only: Name, Email, Phone, City, Payment methods, Delivery methods, Postcode, Street name, House number/Apartment, Comment. And I need to put them all on one page without some steps.

Comment: Opencart doesnt have such option, you need to use checkout module, there are some on the market to asquire.

Comment: @Nerius, which one can you recommend me?

Comment: hm, i can't, but majority of sites i worked with were using this 'AJAX Quick Checkout'